# Cors error while retrieving the data from express api to the react app though ngrok server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors, ngrok

No matter how hard I tried and looked for solutions online, none of them worked.

I have set the node express API by installing the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) library.

```
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
```

also set the headers as

```
  res.headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
      "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With, access_token",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
  };
```

and now all my stuff working fine in my old system, I have recently changed my laptop, and am stuck with this error in frontend side. here I have set up APIs to react with the ngrok server

this is an error

[image: stack]

`post` method APIs working fine the data is adding the database but retrieving from DB `get` method, `put` method, and `delete` method getting cors error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set up CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) for your Node.js Express API to allow cross-origin requests. The code you've shown seems mostly correct, but there are a couple of adjustments needed.

```
const express = require("express");

const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

// Apply the CORS middleware before your routes

app.use(cors());

// Your routes and other middleware come here

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: I did  it correctly and All my code stuff working on the old pc now I have changed the pc and am stuck with this error

Comment: is there any relationship b/w Cors and the system?

Comment: @sumanth did you use any extensions on your web browser previously to avoid cross platform errors?

Comment: CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is a browser security feature that controls how web pages from one domain can request resources from another domain. Do you run both FE and BE locally?

Comment: Yes both run locally in different system.

Comment: as it worked on your pre pc, this error might cause due to missing or outdated dependencies. Compare your current and pre package.json files to ensure that you have installed packages with same version. And check by clearing cache or in a different browser.

Comment: or try example in http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Comment: current and previous node version, npm version, and cors library, express version are the same, and getting error